# Admin Module frontpage has gone - How do I get it back?

Tags: 7

I took the liberty to upgrade to v7.25 today; four hours later (after trying to get back to where I was 8 hours before) I had to used Backup and Migrate to restore my previous v7.24. I've tried numerous update.php attempts but my Admin Module page just will not show via /admin/modules path. I can get admin/uninstall but any attempt to get back to /admin/modules gives me a black white screen so I cannot manage any modules.

Can anyone suggest a solution. I'm aware of Drush and have it to hand, but not too aufait at present (I'm on an Ubuntu desktop with localhost).

I do get a PDO error starting as:
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'has_children' in 'field list':......

if that has any influence.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using phpMyAdmin. Backup again, then show the system table. Change the status of the problem module from 1 to  0 from phpMyAdmin. Then refresh Drupal pages to see if it resolves it. Other modules might be the issue so try process of eleimaination, toggling 1 to 0. If the 0 works, try and uninstall then reinstall if practical.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks for that helpful tip. I never thought of the tables. We learn something new everyday! (-:

Comment: Since I've been playing around with Drush today, can this problem be fixed with a Drush command, if so, anyone care to share? Maybe simply un-install/re-install the 'Modules' Module?

Comment: @drupalist suggested this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/101951/6395