# How to fix - PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]

Tags: 7, database

I cannot seem to get rid of this error after numerous updates, anyone got any ideas/advice how to fix it as my Admin Modules doesn't want to load at all. I'm running D7.26 on this project.
Thanks.

Reports as:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'has_children' in 'field list': UPDATE {menu_links} SET
>   menu_name=:db_update_placeholder_0, plid=:db_update_placeholder_1,
>   link_path=:db_update_placeholder_2,
>   router_path=:db_update_placeholder_3, hidden=:db_update_placeholder_4,
>   external=:db_update_placeholder_5,
>   has_children=:db_update_placeholder_6,
>   expanded=:db_update_placeholder_7, weight=:db_update_placeholder_8,
>   depth=:db_update_placeholder_9, p1=:db_update_placeholder_10,
>   p2=:db_update_placeholder_11, p3=:db_update_placeholder_12,
>   p4=:db_update_placeholder_13, p5=:db_update_placeholder_14,
>   p6=:db_update_placeholder_15, p7=:db_update_placeholder_16,
>   p8=:db_update_placeholder_17, p9=:db_update_placeholder_18,
>   module=:db_update_placeholder_19,
>   link_title=:db_update_placeholder_20,
>   options=:db_update_placeholder_21,
>   customized=:db_update_placeholder_22 WHERE (mlid =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_update_placeholder_0] =>
>   navigation [:db_update_placeholder_1] => 0 [:db_update_placeholder_2]
>   => catalog [:db_update_placeholder_3] => catalog [:db_update_placeholder_4] => 1 [:db_update_placeholder_5] => 0
>   [:db_update_placeholder_6] => [:db_update_placeholder_7] => 0
>   [:db_update_placeholder_8] => 0 [:db_update_placeholder_9] => 1
>   [:db_update_placeholder_10] => 420 [:db_update_placeholder_11] => 0
>   [:db_update_placeholder_12] => 0 [:db_update_placeholder_13] => 0
>   [:db_update_placeholder_14] => 0 [:db_update_placeholder_15] => 0
>   [:db_update_placeholder_16] => 0 [:db_update_placeholder_17] => 0
>   [:db_update_placeholder_18] => 0 [:db_update_placeholder_19] => system
>   [:db_update_placeholder_20] => Catalog [:db_update_placeholder_21] =>
>   a:0:{} [:db_update_placeholder_22] => 0 [:db_condition_placeholder_0]
>   => 420 ) in menu_link_save() (line 3208 of /var/www/sitename/includes/menu.inc).

Comment: See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/99353/7641. It's about disabling modules at the database.

Comment: This will most probably be closed due to being off topic  as a bug in your installation, but what is going on here is the `menu_links` table in your database *should* have a `has_children` small int field in it and for some reason no longer does.  So, you will have to do a re-install of your drupal or go in with a database person and recreate that table field.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, helpful. Yes my DB for this project has a 'has_childrenexpanded' but no has_children. I wonder if I can simply add a new field into the DB without upsetting the Drupal system, it will it merely make it unstable and fallover? I'm confident to hack it myself, or remove any non required bits on advice.